# How to get voice stream from Bot client(emulator) using Microsoft Bot framework

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, botframework

I have an issue regarding bot building (Microsoft Bot Framework). The scenario should be like this- for the the first step I need to test on bot emulator(client). The requirement would be to get the voice from client as a stream (as well as need kind of event that can handle is user speaking or not) and this stream should be passed to the bot web app(server).  From The server than I can use speech api to convert that stream to text. Is there anyone who has an idea:  how to achieve this in .Net(C#)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is something like the [bing speech API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech/) which you can convert speech to text or text to speech.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. Actually I have done that already. But I don't want to upload .wav file to the speech API rather I want when user speaks to the bot, this voice should be taken as input message activity. After that I can easily recognise text via API with this voice stream. In short I want speech recognition should be done on server side not client side. Hope, Now the functionality is clear. And Thank you very much for your quick response.

Comment: How did you get the stream @ArifulIslam

Comment: Did u ever find a solution to this